# IIS crashes at startup - inetinfo.exe - memory could not be read

Tags: iis, windows-xp

Running

- Windows XP SP3
- IIS 5.1

I get this error when I boot my PC.

`Application popup: inetinfo.exe - Application Error : The instruction at "0x5aa3b134" referenced memory at "0x00000004". The memory could not be "read".`

when I try to navigate to a http://localhost/ I get this error

`Faulting application inetinfo.exe, version 5.1.2600.5512, faulting module w3svc.dll, version 5.1.2600.5512, fault address 0x0001b134.`

**System Event log:**

`Event ID: 7031 - The IIS Admin service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 1 milliseconds: Run the configured recovery program.`

followed by
`Event ID: 7034 - The World Wide Web Publishing service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s)`

IIS Admin and World Wide Web Publishing services do restart but keep failing the same way.

Any ideas what the problem could be or how to further diagnose?
I tried this question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/54791/iis-crashes-at-startup-inetinfo-exe-memory-could-not-be-read) and got no takers.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a tricky one.  Try running memory diagnostics that your hardware vendor provides. It may be the physical memory on the computer.

If that comes up clean, what are you running under http://localhost?  Try ensuring that you have just a test.html page without any web.config, global.asa(x) or other application files.  See if it fails for that too.

I would also look for any clues further up in Event Viewer during the boot-up.

Comment: Event viewer looked clean, otherwise.  I'll try the diagnostic, although I don't seem to be having memory issues with other apps. And yes, I'm just hitting a generic 'help.gif'

Comment: Possibly the order that Windows boots and runs in causes IIS to hit the bad memory each time.  You could try swapping DIMMs and see if the error moves.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something got corrupted, what if you uninstall all of the world wide web publishing from the windows components on add/remove programs, restart and install again.

Comment: That was my first instinct, except I reinstalled the entire IIS component.  I may try this again.